# Wordpress shows Index /

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu-16.04

When I open my website URL it shows Index /

1) I have index.php in the same directory 
2) Config file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
has following code:

```
<Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/intricare>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

If I Refresh the URL again it loads the website without issue. 
URL: intricare.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a cache somewhere on your network. When you manually refresh the site, your browser sends an extra header telling the server it desires a fresh copy: `cache-control: no-cache`.

If that header is sent, the current/correct version of the page is returned. If it is not, the cached directory listing is.

If you have curl installed, you can test it yourself with

```
curl https://www.intricare.net/
```

and

`curl -H "cache-control:no-cache" https://www.intricare.net/`

The latter produces the correct output.
If you're using any caching plugins: make them clear the cache. It might also be your hosting provider that is providing the cache, in that case look at their FAQs or ask them how to clear it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction. I have deleted plugins related to caching. I am using the Azure dedicated server for this. So there is no provider caching issue here. Maybe some issue with Apache caching.

Comment: Apache usually does not cache unless you've built some custom configuration. You're also using CloudFlare it seems, have you set up caching manually in their system? By default, they don't cache HTML contents, but maybe you changed that by accident?

Comment: Yes, correct. I was trying to add caching on the server side but ran into some issues, now I have removed those changes but I think the cache is still present, need to clear the cache. I have lots of thing under /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk

Comment: Solved this by disabling the file_cache, cache, cache_disk modules. Thanks for the help.